# power query Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Function to type List in power query

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to run the query in power query editor and it failed with  below error

[image]

where as the same query works fine in winserver 2016 and it fails with above error in win server 2019. Am I missing any thing ?

I did compared the settings and everything looks good.

```
let
  //Get data Report H1
  Source1 = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("\\path\filename.xlsx"), null, true), 
  #"classic_Sheet1" = Source1{[Item = "classic", Kind = "Sheet"]}[Data], 
  #"Trimmed Text1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"classic_Sheet1", Text.Trim), 
  #"Third Row as Header1" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.Skip(#"Trimmed Text1", 2)), 
  #"Selected Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(
    #"Third Row as Header1", 
    {" ID", " Status", "Customer Id ", "Agent", "Leg"}
  ), 

  //Get Report H2
  Source2 = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("\\path\filename.xlsx"), null, true), 
  #"classic_Sheet2" = Source2{[Item = "classic", Kind = "Sheet"]}[Data], 
  #"Trimmed Text2" = Table.TransformColumns(#"classic_Sheet2", Text.Trim), 
  #"Third Row as Header2" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.Skip(#"Trimmed Text2", 2)), 
  #"Selected Columns2" = Table.SelectColumns(
    #"Third Row as Header2", 
    {" ID", "Status", "Customer Id ", "Agent", "Leg"}
  )

in
  #"Excluded IDs"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pointing you to the problem:
Table.TransformColumns expects a **list** as the second parameter,
while you are providing a **function**:

```
Table.TransformColumns(
   table as table, 
   transformOperations as list, 
   optional defaultTransformation as nullable function, 
   optional missingField as nullable number
) as table
```

Please read the official documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-transformcolumns

The issue has nothing to do with *winserver 2016* or *winserver 2019*.

Answer (score 0):

You want something along these lines

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"classic_Sheet1",{{"ColumnNameHere", Text.Trim, type text}})

= Table.TransformColumns(#"classic_Sheet1"",{{"ColumnNameHere", Text.Trim, type text}, {"DifferentColumnNameHere", Text.Trim, type text}})
```